# capacitor in ac and dc circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance

In a dc circuit work done by battery=QV while energy stored in capacitor =(QV)/2 loss in energy=(QV)/2
While a capacitor in ac circuit has a no power loss.why is it so? Shouldn't heat be lost in ac circuit capacitor too while charging.

Answer (score 2):

A  DC battery provides a constant Voltage across the circuit to which it is connected, be it a Resister, Capacitor, Inductor or any combination of these. On the other hand an AC generator provides a alternating sinusoidal voltage across the circuit to which it is connected.

You must remember that in any circuit if for a infinitesimal time $dt$ an amount of charge $dq$ is passed then the work done in that infinitesimal time interval by any *voltage source*(AC or DC) is $$dW=V(t)dq.\tag{1}$$ We know that $\dfrac{dq}{dt}=i(t)$, where $i(t)$ is the current at any time instant $t$. We usually write current as $i$ because it is understood that $i$ is just $i(t)$, that is current at any time instant(also called instantaneous value of current). Similarly $V(t)$ is written as $V$.
Now to calculate the amount of *work done* by any *voltage source* form time $0$ second to $t$ second we integrate the equation 1 from $0$ to $t$, that is
$$W=\int_0^t Vdq.$$
Let's come to your question now

> In a dc circuit work done by battery=QV

This is only true if the circuit is purely resistive, that is can be modeled as:
[image]
Since the circuit is purely resistive the current remains constant until the voltage is not changed. This is basically implied by Ohm's law$-$ Current $i$ at any instant is $\dfrac{V}{R}$, where $R$ is the resistance of the circuit. This means $\dfrac{dq}{dt}=i=constant$ or $q(t)=\int_0^ti(dt)=i\int_0^tdt=it$, that is the total amount of charge $q(t)$ that has been crossed across the circuit uptill time $t$ is $it=\dfrac{V}{R}t$. The work done by the DC battery in time 0 to $t$ is $$W=\int_0^tV dq=V\int_0^tidt=Vit=Vq.$$
Let at time $t=t_0$ the charge crossed is $Q$ then the amount of work done by the DC battery in moving this charge $Q$ across the circuit is $VQ.$

> while energy stored in capacitor =(QV)/2 loss in energy=(QV)/2

We can use the equation 1 again to find how much work is done by an external agency in building a charge $Q$ across the capacitor.
Recall that Voltage $V$ across the capacitor at any time instant $t$ when a charge $q(t)$ is at its plates is given by $V=\dfrac{q(t)}{C}$. As the applied voltage across the capacitor rises the amount of charge stored in it also rises. Also we know that Work done = Energy, that is the amount of work done in building a charge $Q$ is equal to the energy stored in the capacitor.
Work done on a capacitor in building a charge $$Q= \int_0^{q(t)} Vdq=\dfrac{q(t)}{C}dq=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{q^2}{C}=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{q}{C}q=\dfrac{1}{2}V(t)q(t)$$ 
At $t=t_0$ say $V(t_0)=V$ and $q(t_0)=Q$. The work done uptill time $t_0$ is $\dfrac{1}{2}QV$.
*It is to be noted that the amount of energy $\dfrac{1}{2}QV$ is not lost. It is still stored in the capacitor, which can be used in future. To understand the charged capacitor has energy in it consider this situation: Two metallic plates having charge $+Q$ and $-Q$ respectively on them are initially placed very close to each other, these are now separated by a distance $d$ from each other. In separating the plates we have to apply external force on the palates because the opposite charges on the plates attracts each other. Kinda potential energy is increased(like in stretching a spring) which is supplied by the external agency. Similarly if the capacitor is a charged by a DC battery the energy will be supplied by the battery. This energy $\dfrac{1}{2}QV$ can be converted to pure heat if the capacitor is completely discharged by connecting it to a resister*

> ...While a capacitor in ac circuit has a no power loss.why is it so?

The above written line is ambiguous, instantaneous power is not zero, average power is zero. Read somewhere about electric power e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power). A better sense would be:

> If we connect a pure capacitor to an AC generator for a long time, should not the generator keep giving energy to the capacitor, that is in contrast to a DC voltage source why the generator will not give energy to capacitor, that is why the average power is zero?

*The answer is that the AC voltage source gives energy to the capacitor while the current  and applied voltage both have same signs and the capacitor gives back this energy to the AC voltage source while applied voltage and current both have opposite signs.*
This can be better understand by looking at the *waveform of a purely capacitive circuit* in the steady state.
[image: image 2]
From phase $0^0$ to $90^0$ $V$ and $i$ both are positive, the instantaneous power $P(t)$ is also positive, that is the energy $\int_0^{\pi/2}P(t)dt$ given to the capacitor by a the AC voltage source is positive. This means energy is given by the source to the capacitor. 
From phase $90^0$ to $180^0$ $V$ and $i$ have opposite signs, the instantaneous power $P(t)$ is negative, that is the energy $\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}P(t)dt$ given to the capacitor by a the AC voltage source is negative.  This means energy is given back to the AC voltage source by the capacitor.
The net energy given to the capacitor from $0$ to $\pi$ is $0$, the average power from $0$ to $\pi$ is also $0$.
Similarly the average power from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ is also $0$. Hence in one complete cycle the energy given to the capacitor is $0$. The average power during one complete cycle is $0$.
The energy given in $N$ cycles will also be $0$. So it does not matter for how long the capacitor is connected to the AC voltage source, the average power remains zero.
To your last line of the question:

> Shouldn't heat be lost in ac circuit capacitor too while charging.

I do not know what are you trying to say. To me this does not make any *sense*. I am speechless on this.

Answer (score 0):

You are sort of confusing two things here.  But power is only lost in a circuit with LRC components with resistors (R) as they have impedance that is real, that is, resistance.  The impedance of capacitors and inductors is not real, meaning no power is lost.  What this means in practical terms is that power can be temporarily stored in an electric (C) or magnetic field (L).  A perfect LC oscillator would oscillate forever, but trace resistance in any real circuit causes the oscillation to die out over time.